# Very remedial calculus.

Tags: summation

It has been awhile, and I know this is very basic, but if someone would help me just get this, I know I can start retraining my brain.
Basically it is this.
I have :

number of digits x

position of digit y

value of digit z

so, iterating through the digits (from left to right) I want to add the product of each value and 2^y-1.

Not sure how clear the question is. I can almost see the equation in my mind, but it has been so long.

Thanks.

Comment: Write down a 3 digit number. What would your expression look like? try it for a few 3 digit numbers. Try it for a 4 digit number. Try it for an x digit number.

Comment: well, in the case of a binary number 1011 = (1x2^3) + (0x2^2) + (1x2^1) + (1x2^0) - but, it doesn't have to be binary, 2 could be a variable that represents a base.

Comment: writing the program is no problem... expressing it as a mathematical equation is proving to be difficult (though, I know this is actually pretty simple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, so you wanted:

$$\sum_{y = 1}^x z_y2^{y-1}$$

where y is the position of digit *from the right* (righmost = position $1$), or

$$\sum_{y = 1}^x z_{x-y+1}2^{y-1}$$

where y is the position of digit *from the left* (leftmost = position $1$), which is the same as

$$\sum_{y = 1}^x z_{y}2^{x-y}$$

(if you want make the sum from the left - most significant digit with position $1$ - to the right), or - without $\sum$ symbol -

$$z_{1}2^{x-1} + z_{2}2^{x-2} + \dots + z_{x}2^{0}$$

Comment: I am embarrassed... I was so close. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.